# pair up files with matching extensions

Tags: bash, find, file-extension

Let's say I have this list of files:

a.1
a.2
a.3
b.1
b.2

Is there a bash one-liner that could find the one 'a' file for which there is no 'b' with the same extension?  (i.e. **a.3: no match**)
I'm sure I could write a short bash/perl script to do this.
But I would like to know if there is any "trick" for this (of course, GNU tools are at my disposal; awk, sed, find ...)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
ls -1 [ab].* | sort -t . -k 2 | uniq -u -s2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my bash one-liner

```
for afile in a*; do bfile=${afile/a/b}; test -f $bfile || echo $afile; done
```

I like the above solution since it only uses bash and no other tools. However, to showcase the power of Unix tools, the next solution uses 4: ls, sed, sort, and uniq:

```
ls [ab]* | sed 's/b/a/' | sort | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Perl:

```
perl -le 'for (<a*>) { /(.*)\.(.*)/; print "$1.$2" if !-e "b.$2"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

bash version 4 has associative arrays, so you can do this:

```
declare -A a_files
while read -r filename; do
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    case "${filename%.*}" in 
        a) a_files[$ext]="$filename" ;;
        b) unset a_files[$ext] ;;
    esac
done < <(ls [ab].*)
echo "non-matched 'a' files: ${a_files[@]}"
```

Or, with awk:

```
ls [ab].* | awk -F. '
    $1 == "a" {a_files[$2] = $0} 
    $1 == "b" {delete a_files[$2]}
    END {for (ext in a_files) print a_files[ext]}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'Dir["a.*"].each{|x|puts x if not File.exist? "b."+x.scan(/a\.(\d+)/)[0][0]}'
```